# How to set a fixed session id?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I have 2 different session id's on 5 different php pages in the same directory on the same host.

- I call session_start(); right after the php-tag on top of every page
- I converted all the pages to utf-8 without DOM
- I set all file permissions to 644
- I tried clearing my browser cache
- I tried clearing the sessions using the script below

  ```
   session_start();

  // Initialize the session.
  // If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!

  session_unset();
  // Unset all of the session variables.
  $_SESSION = array();

  // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
  // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
  if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
      $params = session_get_cookie_params();
      setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
          $params["path"], $params["domain"],
          $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
      );
  }

  // Finally, destroy the session.
  session_destroy();
  ```

To no avail.
How do I fix this bug?

Comment: <?php
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION=array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
?>

Answer (score 0):

If you use `unset($_SESSION);` that should remove all current sessions I believe.

Then, to set a global session you just do

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = "0001"
```

And then call it by using `$_SESSION['user_id']`.

Make sure, like you do in the demo above, that you have `session_start();` at the top of pages you want to call session variables on.

That might not be the most up to date way, but that's how I've been doing it - just with the unset being assigned to each part of the session array instead of the whole thing.